# I'm trying to write a sorting algorithm in C++ for practice but it doesnt work

Tags: c++

when i run it it lists all the integers in the array but then it drops the last three and and loops forever. i cant figure it out, some constructive criticism would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int ary[8] = {3, 7, 8, 1, 3, 45, 19};
int len (sizeof(ary)/sizeof(ary[0]));
int right = 1;
int g;
int g2;

int main()
{
    while(right != len)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
            std::cout << ", " << ary[i];

        std::cout << "\n";
        usleep(120000);

        for(int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
        {
            if(ary[i] <= ary[i + 1])
            {
                right++;
            }
            else
            {
                g = ary[i];
                g2 = ary[i + 1];
                ary[i] = g2;
                ary[i + 1] = g;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the last valid index into an array of size N is N-1

Comment: This doesn't look like it will sort. You are just swapping elements if they are out of order, but you pass the array once. Practically, you need to do it N^2 times, to ensure the entire array is sorted. N is the length of the array.

Comment: I recommend using a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to single step through your code, looking at values in variables.

Comment: Another debugging idea:  after each swap, print the entire array, with indices.

Answer (score 1):

so what you have tried to do here looks something like bubble sort.
i have fixed the bugs in your code, here's a working version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int ary[8] = {3, 7, 8, 1, 3, 45, 19};
int len (sizeof(ary)/sizeof(ary[0]));
int right = 1;
int g;
int g2;

int main()
{
    while(right != len)
    {
        // the value of the variable 'right' needs to be reset to 1 everytime you loop
        right = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            std::cout << ", " << ary[i];

        std::cout << "\n";
        usleep(120000);

        // as arrays in c++ are zero-indexed, the last element is index len - 1
        for(int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
        {
            if(ary[i] <= ary[i + 1])
            {
                right++;
            }
            else
            {
                g = ary[i];
                g2 = ary[i + 1];
                ary[i] = g2;
                ary[i + 1] = g;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

there is one thing that really caught my eyes and is really bad practice : the way you swapped variables

```
// you only need at most 3 variables to swap
g = ary[i];
ary[i] = ary[i+1];
ary[i+1] = g;
// or you can do built-in:
std::swap(ary[i], ary[i+1]);
```

even though trying to figure stuff out by yourself is good practice and usually helps, in this case I think you should read some documentation.
for reference, this is what a conventional bubble sort looks like:

```
#include <iostream>

int a[] = {3, 7, 8, 1, 3, 45, 19};
const int len = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);

int main () {
  for (int i=0; i<len; ++i) {
    for (int j=i+1; j<len; ++j) {
      if (a[i] > a[j])
        std::swap(a[i], a[j]);
    }
  }
  for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
    std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
  return 0;
}
```

thanks for your time and good luck coding (:

Answer (score 0):

it goes forever becuase the for-loop will compare the last item i[8] with i[8 + 1] and i[8 + 1] is null
so to solve this problem

```
for(int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
```

instead of

```
for(int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
```

try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int ary[8] = {3, 7, 8, 1, 3, 45, 19};
int len (sizeof(ary)/sizeof(ary[0]));
int Round = 0;
int g;
int g2;

int main()
{
    while(Round != len)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            std::cout << ", " << ary[i];

        std::cout << "\n";
        usleep(120000);

        for(int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
        {
            if(ary[i] <= ary[i + 1])
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                g = ary[i];
                g2 = ary[i + 1];
                ary[i] = g2;
                ary[i + 1] = g;
            }
        }
        Round++;
    }
}
```